# Dagger2 inject lateinit var presenter in activity not working

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I want to use dagger for my mvp pattern,
but lateinit presenter will not initialized when I call its function.
Presenter is not private.

here is my dagger ViewModule which provide activity as view for presenter

```
@Module
class ViewModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAView(): AView = MainActivity()
}
```

PresenterModule

```
@Module
class PresenterModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAPresenter(repo: ARepo, view: AView): APresenter = APresenter(repo, view)



}
```

RepoModule

```
@Module
class RepoModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideARepo(): ARepo = ARepo()
}
```

And my APresenter constructor

```
class APresenter @Inject constructor(var repo: ARepo, var view: AView) {

    fun showHelloWorld() {
        val i = repo.repo()
        Log.d("main", "aPresenter repo : $i")
        view.helloWorld()
    }
}
```

Component

```
@Component(modules = [PresenterModule::class, RepoModule::class, ViewModule::class])
@Singleton
interface PresenterComponent {
    fun injectMain(view: AView)
}
```

MainActivity which implements AView interface and inject presenter

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AView, BView {

    @Inject
    lateinit var aPresenter: APresenter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val component = DaggerPresenterComponent.create()
        component.injectMain(this)

        // but this presenter will not init at this time and cause
        // lateinit property not init exception.
        aPresenter.showHelloWorld()
}
```

Comment: `fun provideAView(): AView = MainActivity()` you cannot do this, MainActivity is created by the system and not you

Comment: i did what @mouse said and it did solved the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the exact type in `inject(...)` methods of the `Component` interface. Otherwise, the members won't be injected. (See this [comment](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/73#issuecomment-63252780) for more explanation)

So change your component class to this:

```
@Component(modules = [PresenterModule::class, RepoModule::class, ViewModule::class])
@Singleton
interface PresenterComponent {
    fun injectMain(view: MainActivity) //<-- The AView is changed to MainActivity
}
```